# Add a header row and a time column to a generated HTML table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these two working JavaScript functions

https://github.com/cryptomanxxx/Random2DArrayPlusHtmlTable 
https://cryptomanxxx.github.io/Random2DArrayPlusHtmlTable/

that 1) generates some random data 2) creates a HTML table for such data. There are two problems.

1) The HTML table column headings (the first row in the HTML table) are missing. Which is the simples way to add a row (should be the first row) with column headings to the HTML table? The column heading row should say something generic like this: variable 1, variable 2, variable 3 etc etc

2) The HTML table does not have a column with timestamps. A new column (first column) with timestamps would also be nice like: time 1, time 2, time 3 etc etc

It is obvious that I have not managed to understand how the code works because if I did it would be easy to modify the code. The complexity is overwhelming.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaS.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="div1">

</body>

<script>  htmlTable(RandomArray(8, 4));   </script>

</html>
```

```js
function RandomArray(rows, cols) {
    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        arr.push([]);
        arr[i].push(new Array(cols));

        for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = Math.random();
        }
    }
    console.log(arr);
    return arr;
}


function htmlTable(d) {
    var data = d;
    var html = '<table><thead><tr></tr></thead><tbody>';

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
        html += '<tr>';
        for (var j = 0, rowLen = data[i].length; j < rowLen; ++j) {
            html += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    $(html).appendTo('#div1') ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't stress about the complexity, it gets easier the longer you play with it.

1) If you want column headers, that's what `th` tags are for... and they should go inside the `thead` tags you already have, like this:

```
var html = '<table><thead><tr><th>Timestamp</th><th>Variable 1</th><th>Variable 2</th><th>Variable 3</th><th>Variable 4</th></tr></thead><tbody>';
```

Read more about HTML tables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp).

2) If you want an additional column, add in a value (*a `td` - short for table data*) before the loop that adds the randomize values

```
...
html += '<tr>';
html += '<td>' + new Date().getTime() + '</td>'    <------ NEW CODE TO ADD ANOTHER VALUE
for (var j = 0, rowLen = data[i].length; j < rowLen; ++j) {
...
```

You can learn more about dates, both creating them and displaying them, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp).

All said and done, your function would look like:

```
function htmlTable(d) {
    var data = d;
    var html = '<table><thead><tr><th>Timestamp</th><th>Variable 1</th><th>Variable 2</th><th>Variable 3</th><th>Variable 4</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; ++i) {
        html += '<tr>';
        html += '<td>' + new Date().getTime() + '</td>'
        for (var j = 0, rowLen = data[i].length; j < rowLen; ++j) {
            html += '<td>' + data[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    $(html).appendTo('#div1') ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I managed to solve it myself but in in a different way by adding the headers to the RandomArray data function which is not optimal. I want to keep all HTML in a separate JavaScript function. I think your provided code is better because it is shorter and it is more generic. I even managed to plot the random walks. https://github.com/cryptomanxxx/RandomWalksPlusHtmlTablePlusPlot . I love the result but I will study your code and learn from it. Thx. https://cryptomanxxx.github.io/RandomWalksPlusHtmlTablePlusPlot/